# How to use an Access form to update a one to many relationship in reverse?

Tags: ms-access

I'm making a database for movies. I have a movies table which includes fields for Directors, Writers, and Actors. Each of these fields allows you to select many different directors, writers, and actors from tables created for each category.

Now, I have a movie edit form where the user can select which directors, writers and actors, and these are fairly straightforward to accomplish. However, what I want to do is, for example, a form for "Add a new Actor" which will allow the user to enter the Actor's name and then allow the user to select which movies that actor has been in. This part I'm not quite sure how to do. Normally you select the movie, and then select which people were involved in it, but this way would be backwards and I don't know how to set that up. I know how to query which movies each actor has been in, but I don't know how to essentially "add a movie" to that list.

Basically, I want to use a listbox to select a movie, and then basically have it add that actor to the "Actors" field for that movie. I'm not sure exactly the best design for that.

Comment: Have you tried an Actors main  form with a Movies subform? The subform will need to be based on an ActorMovie junction table with suitable combobox.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do it with an Append Query:

```
INSERT INTO Movies ( Actors.[Value] )
SELECT [Forms]![Select Movies for Actor]![ID] AS Expr1
WHERE ((([ID])=[Forms]![Select Movies for Actor]![lstAllMovies]));
```

This appends the actor into the Movie record's "Actors" field, based on the movie selected in the "Select Movies for Actor" form. I then just run this query from a command button on the form.

I should similarly be able to remove a movie by using a delete query.